# Sequence and Series Solver

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator, math-expression-eval

I made a sequence and series solver just for helping me solve homework, and I'm in dire need of ways to make it further compact and efficient, since I used brute force.

If you want to see what this is supposed to do, please see my [github](https://github.com/MahdeenSky/MicroPythonCalculator/tree/master/MY%20PROJECTS/Sequence%20%26%20Series%20Solver).

This Python code is meant for the fx-cg50 calculator's **micropython**, where there are a lot of functions that don't work including fractions, some mathematical functions such as `math.gcd` and `math.isclose`. So I really require some advice or coding tricks to simplify my program.

Disclaimer: I'm only an A-Level student of 16 years; consider me a beginner. I know `eval` is insecure, but I'm not planning on uploading this online; it's only for my personal use.

```py
# just to make the input_checker function smaller and to eliminate repeated code, responsible for iterating through a list of inputs
def three_variables_looper_arithmetic():
    count_list = [input("enter a1: "), input("enter n: "), input("enter d: ")]
    count_list = [float(eval(count)) for count in count_list if isinstance(count, str)]
    return count_list

# just to make the input_checker function smaller and to eliminate repeated code, responsible for iterating through a list of inputs
def three_variables_looper_geometric():
    count_list = [input("enter a1: "), input("enter r: "), input("enter n: ")]
    count_list = [float(eval(count)) for count in count_list if isinstance(count, str)]
    return count_list


# loops through all the inputs of a given situation based on whether its arithmetic
# or not, and checks whether the input is string like "6/2" so it could evaluate it, allows input of fractions
def input_checker(choice_main, choice_sub, L):
    if choice_main == 'arithmetic':
        if choice_sub == 'a_nth':
            return three_variables_looper_arithmetic()

        elif choice_sub == 'sum_to_nth_without_L':
            return three_variables_looper_arithmetic()

        elif choice_sub == 'sum_to_nth_with_L':
            count_list = [input("enter a1: "), input("enter n: "), L]
            count_list = [float(eval(count)) for count in count_list if isinstance(count, str)]
            return count_list

        elif choice_sub == "a_nth_exceed":
            count_list = [input("enter a1: "), input("enter r/d: ")]
            count_list = [float(eval(count)) for count in count_list if isinstance(count, str)]
            return count_list

        elif choice_sub == "sum_to_nth_without_L_exceed":
            count_list = [input("enter a1: "), input("enter r/d: ")]
            count_list = [float(eval(count)) for count in count_list if isinstance(count, str)]
            return count_list

        elif choice_sub == "sum_to_nth_with_L_exceed":
            count_list = [input("enter a1: "), L]
            count_list = [float(eval(count)) for count in count_list if isinstance(count, str)]
            return count_list


    elif choice_main == 'geometric':
        if choice_sub == 'a_nth':
            return three_variables_looper_geometric()

        elif choice_sub == 'sum_to_nth':
            return three_variables_looper_geometric()

        elif choice_sub == 'sum_to_infinity':
            count_list = [input("enter a1: "), input("enter r: ")]
            count_list = [float(eval(count)) for count in count_list if isinstance(count, str)]
            return count_list

        elif choice_sub == "a_nth_exceed":
            count_list = [input("enter a1: "), input("enter r/d: ")]
            count_list = [float(eval(count)) for count in count_list if isinstance(count, str)]
            return count_list

        elif choice_sub == "sum_to_nth_without_L_exceed":
            count_list = [input("enter a1: "), input("enter r/d: ")]
            count_list = [float(eval(count)) for count in count_list if isinstance(count, str)]
            return count_list

# checks if L is an x or not, also based on whether its on the exceed or normal path, and
# an x means L is not present, while a value of L represents it is present and used in calculation
def L_evaluator(L, option, choice_n, value):
    if option == "normal":
        if L == "x":
                    a1, n, d = input_checker(choice_main, choice_n, L)
                    result = (n/2)*(2*a1+(n-1)*d)
                    return result
        else:
                    choice_n = choice_map_sub['x']
                    a1, n, L = input_checker(choice_main, choice_n, L)
                    result = (n/2)*(a1+L)
                    return result

    if option == "exceed":
        if L == "x":
                    a1, d = input_checker(choice_main, choice_n, 0)
                    a1, d = float(a1), float(d)
                    n = 1
                    while True:
                        result = (n/2)*(2*a1+(n-1)*d)
                        if (result >= float(value)):
                            break
                        n += 1
                    return n
        else:
                    choice_n = choice_map_exceed['c']
                    a1, L = input_checker(choice_main, choice_n, L)
                    n = 1
                    while True:
                        result = (n/2)*(a1+L)
                        if (result >= float(value)):
                            break
                        n += 1
                    return n


# finds the first n to exceed a certain value, by using brute force method
def minimum_n_finder(choice_main, choice_map_exceed):
    choice_n_input = None
    if choice_main == "arithmetic":
        while choice_n_input not in ['a', 'b']:
            choice_n_input = input("Enter a for nth\nEnter b for sum\n>> ")
        choice_n = choice_map_exceed[choice_n_input]
        print("enter x in n")

        if choice_n == "a_nth_exceed":
            print("a1+(n-1)d > Value")
            a1, d = input_checker(choice_main, choice_n, 0)
            n = 1
            value = input("Enter the value to exceed: ")
            while True:
                result = a1+(n-1)*d
                if (result >= float(value)):
                    break
                n += 1
            print("The minimum n to exceed is " + str(n))

        if choice_n == "sum_to_nth_without_L_exceed":
            n = 1
            print("Sn=(n/2)(2a1+(n-1)d)>Value\nSn=(n/2)(a1+L)>Value\nEnter x if L is unknown")
            L = input("Enter L: ")
            value = input("Enter the value to exceed: ")
            result = L_evaluator(L, "exceed", choice_n, value)
            print("The minimum n to exceed is " + str(result))


    elif choice_main == 'geometric':
        while choice_n_input not in ['a', 'b']:
            choice_n_input = input("Enter a for nth\nEnter b for sum_to_nth\n>> ")
        choice_n = choice_map_exceed[choice_n_input]

        if choice_n == "a_nth_exceed":
            print("a1(r)^(n-1)>Value")
            a1, r = input_checker(choice_main, choice_n, 0)
            if a1 == 0:
                print("a cannot be 0")
                raise SystemExit
            n = 1
            value = input("Enter the value to exceed: ")
            while True:
                result = a1*(r)**(n-1)
                if (result >= float(value)):
                    break
                n += 1
            print("The minimum n to exceed is " + str(n))

        elif choice_n == "sum_to_nth_without_L_exceed":
            print("Sn=(a1(1-(r)^n))/(1-r)")
            a1, r = input_checker(choice_main, choice_n, 0)
            if a1 == 0:
                print("a cannot be 0")
                raise SystemExit
            n = 1
            value = input("Enter the value to exceed: ")
            while True:
                result = (a1*(1-(r)**n))/(1-r)
                if (result >= float(value)):
                    break
                n += 1
            print("The minimum n to exceed is " + str(n))


# as this code is for a calculator the x button is very easily accessible to shut the whole program.
def stopper():
    stop_or_continue = input("Stop?: enter x then\n>>>  ")
    if stop_or_continue == "x":
        raise SystemExit  

print("Sequence & Series Solver")

# asks whether you want to solve arithmetically or geometrically, depends on the sequence/series
while True:
    choice_main , choice_input_main = None, None
    choices_main_options = ['a','b']
    choice_map_main ={"a": 'arithmetic', "b": 'geometric'}
    while choice_input_main not in choices_main_options:
        choice_input_main = input("a for arithmetic\nb for geometric\n>> ")
    choice_main = choice_map_main[choice_input_main]

    if choice_main == "arithmetic":
        print("Arithmetic: ")
        choice_sub, choice_input_sub = None, None
        choices_sub_options = ['a', 'b', 'c']
        choice_map_sub = {'a': 'a_nth', 'b': 'sum_to_nth_without_L', 'x': 'sum_to_nth_with_L', 'c':'minimum_number_of_terms_to_exceed'}
        while choice_input_sub not in choices_sub_options:
            choice_input_sub = input("a for a_nth term\nb for sum\nc for min_term_to_exceed\n>> ")
        choice_sub = choice_map_sub[choice_input_sub]

        # the variable choice_main refers to whether the choice is arithmetic or geometric
        # choice_sub refers to the types of formulas you'll use in sequences/series
        if choice_sub == "a_nth":
            print("a_nth=a1+(n-1)d")
            a1, n, d = input_checker(choice_main, choice_sub, 0)
            result = a1+(n-1)*d
            print(round(result,4))

        elif choice_sub == "sum_to_nth_without_L":
            print("Sn=(n/2)(2a1+(n-1)d)\nSn=(n/2)(a1+L)\nEnter x if L is unknown")
            L = input("Enter L: ")
            print(round(L_evaluator(L, "normal", choice_sub, 0), 4))

        elif choice_sub == "minimum_number_of_terms_to_exceed":
            choice_map_exceed = {'a': 'a_nth_exceed', 'b': 'sum_to_nth_without_L_exceed', 'c': 'sum_to_nth_with_L_exceed'}
            minimum_n_finder("arithmetic", choice_map_exceed)


    elif choice_main == "geometric":
        print("Geometric: ")
        choice_sub, choice_input_sub = None, None
        choices_sub_options = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        choice_map_sub = {'a': 'a_nth', 'b': 'sum_to_nth', 'c': 'sum_to_infinity', 'd': 'minimum_number_of_terms_to_exceed'}
        while choice_input_sub not in choices_sub_options:
            choice_input_sub = input("a for a_nth term\nb for sum\nc for sum to infinity\nd for min_terms_exceed\n>> ")
        choice_sub = choice_map_sub[choice_input_sub]

        if choice_sub == "a_nth":
            print("a_nth=a1(r)^(n-1)")
            a1, r, n = input_checker(choice_main, choice_sub, 0)
            result = a1*(r)**(n-1)
            print(round(result,4))

        elif choice_sub == "sum_to_nth":
            print("Sn=(a1(1-(r)^n))/(1-r)")
            a1, r, n = input_checker(choice_main, choice_sub, 0)
            try:
                result = (a1*(1-(r)**n))/(1-r)
                print(round(result,4))
            except (ZeroDivisionError, NameError):
                print("r cannot be 1!")

        elif choice_sub == "sum_to_infinity":
            print("S_inf=a1/(1-r)")
            a1, r = input_checker(choice_main, choice_sub, 0)
            if (r > 1):
                print("r cannot be greater than 1")
                raise SystemExit
            try:
                result = a1/(1-r)
                print(round(result,4))
            except (ZeroDivisionError, NameError):
                print("r cannot be 1!")

        elif choice_sub == "minimum_number_of_terms_to_exceed":
            choice_map_exceed = {'a': 'a_nth_exceed', 'b': 'sum_to_nth_without_L_exceed', 'c': 'sum_to_nth_with_L_exceed'}
            minimum_n_finder("geometric", choice_map_exceed)

    stopper()
```

Comment: What would the user enter when asked for `enter a1:`? A mathematical expression?

Comment: yeah i set the prints before the input to show the formula so youd know what you are entering to calculate

Comment: and each input like a1, r/d, is one value not an expression, tho the expression could be 1/2 for example or generally something that isnt whole and could be expressed using only fractions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can just return the list comprehension instead of first overwriting `count_list`. That should save you a few lines without affecting readability.

For all of your if-cases, you could use a dictionary instead. So that if `choice_sub in dict.keys(): dict[choice_sub]`.

Generally, when functions are getting as long as yours are, it's a good idea to start thinking about OOP and classes. And you could separate the "front-end" (all of your prints and inputs) from your "back-end" (the functions/methods performing the calculations). This would also make it easier on yourself if you want to migrate away from a CLI app to something with a graphical interface (which could help make the formatting of the formulas more readable).